# Bash Script to delete specific docker images and containers

Tags: linux, bash, docker, shell, docker-compose

I work with docker images a lot and create the same image again and again after making changes to the code; so I get a lot of leftover images.

[image]

I want to write a bash script that can delete all the docker images with **REPOSITORY == none** or **TAG == none**.
Sometimes the none docker image is being run by a container so it cannot be deleted; then i want the script to delete the container running the image firstly then remove the image.

Currently i am using ***docker rmi {imageId1} {imageId2} ...*** to delete the images. Your help will be appreciated; Thank you.

Comment: I think what you're looking for may `docker image prune`.

Comment: @larsks i dont want to delete all images, only the ones with <none> in Tag or RepositoryName

Comment: `docker image prune` doesn't delete all images (unlesss you ask it to with `--all`). Please take a look at the docs; I think it will do almost exactly what you want.

Comment: @larsks i saw the documentation and ran the command **docker image prune --filter="label=none"** but nothing is removed, can you correct this, Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Use bash command:

```
docker rmi $(docker images | grep none | tr -s ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f 3)
```

This command gets all image IDs that have tag none and then removes them, if the image is being used anywhere use **--force** flag to forcefully delete.

Comment: 'none' could be replaced by any specific tag that you want to remove, 'v1.0' for example.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try :

```
docker rmi $(docker images -f "dangling=true" -q)
```